# How to add attributes to rails params in a controller and pass to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
upload_controller
 def create
  file = @upload.file
  content = File.read file
  params['content'] = content
 end
end
```

Here `params['content']` has proper file content.

```
book_controller
 def create
  @book.description = params['content']
  @book.save
 end
end
```

But `params['content']` in  `book_controller.rb` returns `nil`

How can I pass content from upload controller to book controller?

Comment: are you redirect to book controller from "create" method of upload_controller

Answer (score 0):

May this work

```
  content = File.read file
  redirect_to url_you_want_to_redirect(content: content)
```